# Upgrading SSD on mid 2014 MB: which SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade

I have a pretty simple issue.

The SSD of my mi-2014 Macbook pro (retina - MacBookPro11,1) seems to be too short (256GB).

**So I'm considering buying a 1Tb SSD for my Macbook, but I read, here and there, that not all SSD are compatible** (because of its format, "blade" SSD or something).

So, do you know which 1Tb SSD I could upgrade my Macbook Pro with ?

Answer (score 1):

Without having heard of this sort of incompatibility before, I'd suggest you check out [Other World Computing](http://macsales.com), who have a great reputation for Mac aftermarket parts - including a great line of SSDs. I've been happy with one of their SSDs in an old MacBook Pro myself. Great product backed with a thorough understanding of Apple's product line and fantastic customer service.

And to be clear, I'm not affiliated in any way other than being a happy customer.

**Update:** Thanks to @enguerranws for doing the extra legwork; OWC indeed does have a solution available for the 11,1 in 240GB, 480GB and 1TB [as of at least Dec 2016](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Memory/OWC/Apple-MacBook-Pro-Retina-Upgrades-2013-2015).

Comment: Not sure this answer the question, this is at most a comment to the question. However, this website provides no information about SSD on MacBookPro11,1.

Comment: OWC has now released the new SSD upgrade options for 11,1: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2015